# Taking screenshots of multiple browser tabs

Tags: windows-7, browser, internet-explorer, tabs, screenshot

My browser has 10-20 tabs open and I should go through and take a screenshot of each tab.

Can this be automated somehow?

I am using Internet Explorer but solutions for other browsers are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) can take full page screenshots of browser tabs. It scrolls the page down and stitches the pieces together automatically.

Right-click its tray icon » Capture Internet Explorer from list » All open tabs are listed there
[image]
You might want to automate these repeating clicks by using [TestComplete](http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools) or [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)